# Arch: Is there any chance to use Apache all default for 2 or more virtual hosts?

Tags: debian, arch-linux, apache-httpd, configuration, ansible

I consider establishing an Arch based LAMP.

From reading [this document](https://www.linode.com/docs/web-servers/lamp/how-to-install-a-lamp-stack-on-arch-linux/), it seems there is must configuration to be done just for Apache itself, not to mention MySQL and PHP.

In Debian LAMP there's much less to configure and the basic usage is pretty much "all default".

Is there any chance to use Arch Apache **all default** for 2 or more virtual hosts without all this configuration?

<sub>I didn't find any Ansible galaxy-role to make it easier.</sub>

Comment: I'm not an Arch user, but I believe the philosophy of Arch is to promote a do-it-yourself approach: [Why would I not want to use Arch?](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Frequently_asked_questions#Why_would_I_not_want_to_use_Arch?)

Answer (score 1):

In your documentation link is an example for the virtualhost config `/etc/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`. You can add another `<VirtualHost>`-block below the first one. But ofcourse you will have to configure your virtual hosts...

In my opinion the installation guide for Apache/Mysql/PHP is pretty straight forward and also kept pretty "default". Only 5-6 commands to set up and start a service is not much. No offense, but if this is too much for you, maybe you should consider switching to a different distro.

Comment: Hello. It's not too much for me, I just wondered why is it longer than in Debian where there is only one command to install everything without any further commands but anyway I've learned that in Arch the approach is more "Do it yourself".